What's the earliest reference noting that a NOT gate is the same as a Pauli X operator?
Coming from an electrical/computer engineering background, I knew what a NOT gate is well before I learned about the Pauli matrices.  But the NOT gate is operationally the same as a Pauli X matrix, and I only learned the significance of the Pauli operators much later.  This was certainly very helpful for me to understand more of the physics behind quantum computing.
It was certainly well-known by the mid-1990's.  But before that, was it a folk lemma that:
$$\mathsf{NOT}_{\mathrm{classical}}\simeq X_{\mathrm{quantum}}$$
or were any pre-Shor founders explicitly noting it?
This simple relationship really connects the two worlds of classical circuit design and quantum mechanics and feels profound.

I have been looking into this exact same question on and off for a few years, and honestly I have found it hard to find evidence for who was the first person to explicitly make the connection.
Feynman was clearly aware of the relation between Fredkin's/Toffoli's reversible logic and quantum mechanics, but does not explicitly mention the use Pauli matrices as equivalent operations to that of single-bit classical gates.
I think the earliest account I have found making some level of connection is in Asher Peres' 1985 paper on Reversible logic and quantum computers where he describes implementing reversible computations in terms of the spin matrices:
$$ P_+ = \frac{1}{2}I + s_z = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$ P_- = \frac{1}{2}I - s_z = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$ J_+ = s_x + i s_y = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$ J_- = s_x - i s_y = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
So, here $s_x$ makes an appearance, but he does not explicitly make the link between Pauli $X$ and the $\mathsf{NOT}$ gate in his writing. However, my guess is that this was clear in his mind since he describes implementing two bit operations (like $\mathsf{XOR}, \mathsf{NAND}$) using tensor products of the matrices above.
The first instances I've seen of Pauli matrices being explicitly referred to as single-qubit operations do not happen until 1994/1995, but I think by then many had already established the connection between the $\mathsf{NOT}$ and the Pauli $X$.
The very first very explicit excerpt I've found is from H. F. Chau and F. Wilczek 1995 paper Simple Realization of the Fredkin Gate using a Series Of Two-Body Operators, where they say:
"A quantum NOT gate is a one-in one-out quantum gate [see Fig. 2(a)], performing the unitary transformation $N_{(a)}|\alpha\rangle_a = \sigma_1|\alpha\rangle_a ,$ where $\sigma_i$ are the Pauli spin matrices, ..."
Hopefully there is someone that has a bit more information about this.

Thanks! and glad I'm not the only one curious about the history of this enough to go down a rabbit hole.  I was only vaguely aware of Peres's contributions - thanks for the link!  But I also see it in "Elementary gates for quantum computation" (arXiv) from March 1995, which seems pretty contemporaneous with Chau and Wilczek.

Yeah! The reason I used Chau and Wilczek's paper as an example is because "Elementary gates for quantum computation" includes it in its references, so it predates it at least by a few months (they also thank Chau in the acknowledgments). But yeah, I think all of the big names in that paper were well aware of this relation even years before the paper was published.

Do you agree with me that it's just a coincidence that Feynman drew a NOT gate with an "X" on the wire, and Feynman was only using an X because it's symmetrical (it's its own mirror image) and not because he saw it as a Pauli $X$ operation (where elsewhere he prefixed Pauli operators as $\sigma_x$?)

Yes, I agree. As a matter of fact, I've been working on a website on QC using Python, and that's precisely what I wrote a few months ago: https://learnquantum.io/chapters/01_classical_computing/01_02_reversible_computing.html#reversible-not (see footnote)

Hah! Very nice. I like your website! I read "Quantum Mechanical Computers" as more of a (classical) computer science/computer engineering paper, saying to the engineers "Hey we can do some cool classical stuff with quantum computers!" while I read his earlier talk as a conversation with physicists, saying "Hey, simulating quantum mechanics is really hard, but maybe a quantum computer would be neat!"

Thanks! and yes, I agree. That was exactly my take from both of his papers.
